# In a list, set the default sort column in jhipster

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jhipster

sorry for simple question, but I'm new both to spring, JPA and Jhipster.
I'm following a video tutorial, and in one step the teacher was "customizing" the default view to sort on a custom column. He did so by changing the method in the repository class, to a query that ordered by one of the columns. This works, but I noticed that doing that the UI sort (the sort the UI impose clicking on the column) stopped working.

Debugging i noticed that the reason is that the query filter first by date, then by "pageable".
What is the best practice to apply the "byDate" sort just as a  default, in case the pageable is empty?

I managed to "hack" the system by deep inspecting the page object and with an "if there is an UI sort use repository method A (the one that is natively unsorted), if there is not use repository method B (the one that is already sorted)". What I'm looking for is the "right way", the best practice, because I want to learn to program the way it is supposed to be, and I'm pretty sure that to have a default sort column is not a such exotic request

[Here it is the link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQqlO3IGpTU&t=670s)

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default sorting column of any view in the `[component-name].route.ts`. In that file you will see something like this:

```js
// ...
export const fooRoute: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FooComponent,
    resolve: {
      pagingParams: JhiResolvePagingParams
    },
    data: {
      authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
      defaultSort: 'id,asc',      // <- Look at this line :)
      pageTitle: 'jhipsterApp.foo.home.title'
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
  },
  // ...
```

The default order set by JHipster is by column `id` in ascending order. If you want to set the default order by column `name` descending (just as an example) just change that line to the following:

```js
      defaultSort: 'name,desc',
```

Answer (score 1):

My app is generated via recent JHipster 7.4.1 and uses Vue frontned.
There are no `[component-name].route.ts` files generated.
I tried to add `defaultSort` into `entities.ts` but no luck.

This is working here:
In the `[entity-name].components.ts`,
change

```
    public propOrder = 'id';
```

into

```
    public propOrder = '[your default sort column, e.g. name]';
```